# Find first occurrence of pattern in regex

Tags: regex, web-applications, outsystems

If I am looking through text like this:

```
hello bob hello hello hello
```

I want to find the first instance of hello and take it out, so I use a pattern like this

```
hello
```

When I erase that pattern, this is what the text is

```
bob
```

but what I need is

```
bob hello hello hello
```

How do I modify it to only find the first occurrence of the pattern

Comment: Which language are you using? And what have you tried?

Comment: I guess it is ruby! :)

Comment: @Kent quite a wild guess ;)

Comment: @m.buettner it is not a language, it is outsystems agile platform

Answer (score 2):

My crystal bowl tells me you're using some sort of a `global` modifier in your regexp and if you leave it out then you should get the result you expect. For example in javascript you would use:

```
/hello/
```

instead of:

```
/hello/g
```

Comment: @Kevin: The distinction between global (find all matches) and non-global (find only first match) is not part of the regular expression.  It would be some sort of setting or flag in the call.  I can't seem to find any documentation on regular expression format for outsystems... can you point us to a reference?

Answer (score 1):

In OutSystems, regex functions are provided through extensions, so I'll assume that you are using the `Text` extension. The extension code maps to .NET / Java code and the underlying calls to the regex methods are `Replace(string input, string replacement)` for .NET and `replaceAll(String replacement)` for Java. These will both replace all occurrences of your regexp on the given input string.

Now, several ways into solving your problem...

**If you want to replace in the beginning of the string:**
In the example you've given, the *hello* you're interested in removing is also in the beginning of the input string. In that particular case you could use a regular expression such as `^hello`.

**If you want to replace the first match, anywhere in the string:**
If you're interested in replacing the first occurrence but that can be anywhere in the input string, then you could write an expression such as `hello(.*)` and use as replacement string `$1`. In this case, `$1` would mean the capturing group `(.*)` which would include all further occurrences of *hello*. This works both for [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx) and [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29). Of course this way of doing things is neither pretty nor efficient so...

**If you want to have more regex capabilities:** you can use Integration Studio to download and open the Text extension and add any new methods that you want, although since this extension is included in the platform and can be replaced by an upgrade, I'd suggest creating your own extension and using the Text extension as a template. You could create an extension action very similar to the current `Replace` one but that could take an additional *count* parameter or something similar.